# NSURLConnection not recognized

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have some problem when I try to recognize a `NSURLConnection`.  Simply `imgConnection` is not recognized while `xmlConnection` is.

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if (connection == xmlConnection) {
        [dataFinale appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"XML");
    }
    else if (connection == imgConnection){
        [imgData appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"IMG");
    }

}

NSURLRequest *requestImg = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlImg cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

imgConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestImg delegate:self];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"?

Comment: If i put code inside if(connection==imgConnection) this code no run!

Comment: Did you remember to start the connection? It would help if you posted more code.

Comment: The connection start because the files is downloaded! I start it with: 
NSURLRequest *requestImg = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlImg cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
imgConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestImg delegate:self];